# Marking or Tagging Non-structured Data (Text data) with combination of words

Tags: r, text, mining

I m working on unstructured data (text).
I want to tag back the data with some key words and combination of key words.

I am not able to tag back the data with the combination of words. I want to know where "fraud" AND "misselling" is occurring.

I tried using qdap package 
I was able to tag these two words with OR condition not with AND condition

Below is the code i used

```
library (qdap)

df<- read.csv (file.choose(),header=T) 

####cleaning of text
df$Comment<- strip(df$Comment)##remove capitalization and punctuation

df$Comment<- clean (df$Comment)
df$Comment<- scrubber(df$Comment)
df$Comment<- qprep(df$Comment)

df$Comment<-replace_abbreviation(df$Comment)

terms <- list(
    " fraud ",
    " refund "," cheat ", " cancellation ", "missold", "delay",
      combo1= qcv(fraud,missold) )

df2<-with (df, termco(df$Comment, df$Comment, terms))[["raw"]]###tagging of data with key words
df3<- merge (df, df2, by="Comment")
```

I am using complain data for insurance companies 
Variables I had are

1. Date of complain
2. Brand aganist complain
3. Comment (Complain)

Comment: What about regular expressions in the veins of `grep(paste(terms, collapse="|"), df$Comment)`?

Comment: Hi lukeA, I want to tag back these key-words and combination (all those said fraud and missold together) back to data file so that i can analysis the profile of these cases

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand. Please provide sample data and show what the result should look like.

Comment: sample data https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/46021747/Insurance_Data_Raw_FINAL%20_sample%20data.csv

Comment: and in sample output i want new column with tag for each row where these combination has occurred   https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/46021747/sample%20output.xlsx

Answer (score 0):

Based on you sample xlsx:

```
library(xlsx)
df <- read.xlsx(file="sample output.xlsx", sheetIndex=1)
library(tm)
terms <- stemDocument(c("fraud","refund","cheat", "cancellation", "misselling", "delay"))
mat <- DocumentTermMatrix(x=Corpus(VectorSource(df$Comment)), 
                          control=list(removePunctuation = TRUE,
                                       dictionary = terms, 
                                       stemming = TRUE,
                                       weighting = weightBin))
df2 <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(mat)) 
(df2 <- transform(df2, combo = fraud + missel))
df2
#   cancel cheat delay fraud missel refund combo
# 1      1     0     0     1      1      0     2
# 2      1     0     0     1      1      0     2
# 3      0     0     0     1      1      0     2
df3 <- cbind(df, df2)
df3
```

Comment: Thanks lukeA, but I am getting the same result. Data is again tagged with OR condition, I want all those cases where fraud AND misselling are coming together in same text

Comment: ... that's what the `combo` column holds. You could also use a nested regular expression search like this `grep("mis.?sel", grep("fraud", df$Comment, ignore.case=T, value=T), ignore.case=T)`.